# jsGrid filter sends multiple requests to server > how to filter on data already on the client

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I have a jsGrid that uses a server call (Ajax Post call) a get a lot of records in my grid. This takes some time but it works fine.

Now I want to implement filtering. 
I know when I enter something in a filter box, the filter object gets populated and the LoadData (of jsGrid) is called. I my case the LoadData does a request to the server to fetch the data (again), which take to much time. How can I prevent that and filter on the data I already have in my client? Is there an object where the current data is stored?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Combine server and client side filtering. Cache data received from server inside `loadData` and filter them with js, instead of calling server.